# Detect git subfolder in Visual studio code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a folder where the root folder is not git repository but the underlying `src/` folder is.
So for example I have this

```
 ~/workspace/some_project_folder <-- not a git repository
 ~/workspace/some_project_folder/src <-- git repository
 ~/workspace/some_project_folder/some_other_folder <-- not a git repository
 ~/workspace/some_project_folder/transient_data <-- not a git repository
```

(**Note** this structure is by all means not good but this what I have inherited. I will change this in the future, I just want a workaround for the moment)

I was searching for option to specify that my main git folder is under `src` but could not find any such option.

Is there a way to to recognise subfolders in Visual Studio Code? Currently sticking with the cmd git.

Comment: I wish there was a setting where I could tell VS where the git project is. I usually open the entire WordPress codebase as a the root so my intellisense will pick up functions for goto, etc, but it's not the git folder, that's wp-content.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately there is no support for it in VSCode in ver. 1.15.1 (it's added in 1.16 though, see nr 3).

This is related to the following issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/396 (search for `git`)

You have to set the git project as a main one in VSCode to make git working properly. It means that probably you need to have two VSCode windows to be opened at the same time:

- the first one with `~/workspace/some_project_folder` for general overview,
- the second one with `~/workspace/some_project_folder/src` for seeing
  and handling git changes.

1)
There is an interesting plugin which can make life a bit easier:

Git Project Manager: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felipecaputo.git-project-manager

It can scan your main folder for git repositories in subfolders and you can quickly select the git repo to be opened in a separate window using command 
`GPM: Open Git Project from SubFolder`.

2)
On the other hand in there is a plan to support multiple folders in one workspace in ver. 1.6 using command: `Workspaces: Add Folder to Workspace...`, so you can add the `src` folder separately and it will be visible as a git repo.

However currently this option is only visible in 'insiders' version, which you can download from:

https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders

*Edit:*

3) It seems that ver. 1.6 supports git subfolders finally.

Comment: Using VS Code 1.27 I still see this issue, even after adding the subfolder to the workspace. Changes within it don't show up in the Git side window?

Comment: @SteveBennett I have the same issue with VSCode 1.31.1. VSCode doesn't even recognize the git directory in the subfolder I separately added to the workspace

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37947#issuecomment-460340426

Answer (score 2):

You can add the root folder and subfolder into one workspace. The order is also important, the root folder should be the last one. Then you can track changes in these two folders.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Why isn't VS Code discovering Git repositories in parent folders of workspaces or open files?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/faq#_why-isnt-vs-code-discovering-git-repositories-in-parent-folders-of-workspaces-or-open-files)

> You can control how Git repositories from parent folders are handled using the git.openRepositoryInParentFolders setting. If you would like to restore the old behavior, set the git.openRepositoryInParentFolders setting to always.